# How to sum up a fetched result's number property based on the object's category?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a `NSFetchRequest` that is returning all my saved objects (call them `Item`s) and storing them in an `NSMutableArray`. Each of these `Item`s have a category, an amount, and some other properties. My goal is to check the category of each `Item` and store the sum of the amounts for objects of the same category. So if I had these `Item`s:

- Red; 10.00
- Blue; 20.00
- Green; 5.00
- Red; 5.00
- Green; 15.00

then I would have an array or other type of container than has:

- Red; 15.00
- Blue; 20.00
- Green; 20.00

**What would be the best way to organize the data in such a manner?** I was going to create a object class (call it `Totals`) that just has the category and amount. As I traverse through the fetch results in a for-loop, add `Item`s with the same category in a `Totals` object an store them in a `NSMutableArray`. The problem I ran into with that is that I'm not sure how to check if an array contains a `Totals` object with a specific property. Specifically, a category that already exists. So if 'Red' exists, add the amount to it, otherwise create a new `Totals` object with category 'Red' and a the first `Item`'s amount. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question and to give you generic methods that can prove helpful in many situations, you can use the [myObject isKindOfClass:aClass] method, then the respondsToSelector: method of NSObject.

If you know what are the kind of data you're gonna get.. You can just instantiate an object Totals with Red = 0, Blue = 0, Green = 0, then add amounts accordingly.

As an other option, you can take a look at Key-value coding : [link here](http://theocacao.com/document.page/161/)

you can use the NSMutableDictionary class to achieve that. You will look in your total object (NSMutableDictionary) if key exists, if not, create it, if yes add value.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you mean to use the isKindOfClass method. I know what class going to be returned. I don't, however, know what categories the objects will have. The colors are sample data and there is way more categories than those so I don't want to create an object for each category when, a lot of which, may never be used.

Comment: Oh yeah key-value may work. I haven't got to try it yet. As soon as I do, I'll give you your props.